# How to calculate coordinates using MDS if the square root of the Eigen values are imaginary

Tags: matrices, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I'm currently trying to retrieve the coordinates of nodes using from the distance matrix using MDS

Assuming I have my original coordinates are (0,0), (0,2), (2,0) and (2,2). Hence the Distance matrix will be:

\begin{bmatrix}0 & 2 & 2 & 2.82842712 
\\2 & 0 & 2.82842712 & 2
\\2 & 2.82842712 & 0 & 2
\\2.82842712 & 2 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Decomposition of this Distance matrix will return Eigen Values:
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.21338835 & 0.08838835 & 0.03661165 & 0.08838835
\end{bmatrix}

and Eigen Vectors:
$
U = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\\5.00000000e-01 & 7.07106781e-01  & 5.00000000e-01  & 3.26334304e-01
\\5.00000000e-01 & -1.85675350e-16 & -5.00000000e-01 & -6.27300504e-01
\\5.00000000e-01 & -8.85308358e-17 & -5.00000000e-01 & 6.27300504e-01
\\5.00000000e-01 & -7.07106781e-01 & 5.00000000e-01  & -3.26334304e-01
\end{bmatrix}
$

We could get the final result of the points using the formula:
$X = U \sqrt{S}$

where S is the diagonal matrix of the Eigen Values.

But taking the square-root of the Eigen Value diagonal matrix will return imaginary numbers for some values. And hence it wouldn't be possible to recalculate the original coordinator.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: you don't want to diagonalize the distance matrix, but rather a suitably recentered version which is automatically positive definite. this is explained in the wikipedia article on mds

Comment: @MikeHawk I followed the Wikipedia Steps of a Classical MDS algorithm to find the calculated coordinate matrix X, but the coordinates are all incorrect in the sense that the distance matrix generated from the calculated coordinate matrix X  does not match the original distance matrix.